# What should be done with the "Christmas party slap" question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

So far [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38650/325) has one delete vote, one reopen vote, one offensive flag, and a lot of discussion in comments (some of which are also flagged).  What should be done with this question?  Please discuss here, not in further comments that mostly won't be seen.  Or just act -- if you've got votes in either direction, use 'em.

Comment: Ha! I know who cast that delete vote!

Comment: @JimG - Who is that?

Comment: update: question has been deleted, most likely by [roomba script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this question can be reopened until it becomes a specific, answerable question. Right now the question boils down to "I did something bad, now there are consequences, I have stress, what should I do?".

The comments and answers seem to focus on varying degrees of "OP you shouldn't have done that, deal with the consequences and don't do it again". From my perspective, these are not useful answers to the OP or future google guests.

A similarly themed question on academia, [I was caught cheating on an exam, how can I minimize the damage?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/30539) is a much better question because of its tone as well as listing out specifically what the OP is looking for as an outcome.

The academia question also has fantastic answers that explain why and how the OP should learn from this. Our christmas party slap answers are nowhere near that level of quality yet, and won't be able to reach that level until the quality of the question improves to the point where it is answerable.

**Leave it closed, let the community edit it**, the edits will kick it into the reopen queue and the reopen voters will move it appropriately.

Comment: related: [Aggressive Edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168) -- "When I can see a core question that I think will help the person asking, I make those edits, because I think a question that benefits the asker will be good for them, and good for The Workplace..."

Comment: The question is not real... just like the last one was not real.  There is nothing we can do to help here.

Comment: The question was later automatically deleted as abandoned (the Roomba).  Anybody who still wants to try to save it should probably just start over.